# Extract text from docx in specific index

Tags: java, apache-poi

I used apache poi to extract the content of docx file and to convert it to html format.

The problem is i want to extract the text from the word `Madame` to the word `attach`.

I tried with the below error but i have this error:

> org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.NotOfficeXmlFileException: No
> valid entries or contents found, this is not a valid OOXML (Office
> Open XML) file

```
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(bibliothequePath))) {
        XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(in);

        XWPFWordExtractor ex = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
        String text = ex.getText();

        int start = text.indexOf("Madame");
        int end = text.indexOf("attach");

        String str = text.substring(start, end + 1);

        InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes());
        XWPFDocument targetDocument = new XWPFDocument(targetStream); // error

        XHTMLOptions options = XHTMLOptions.create().URIResolver(new FileURIResolver(new File("word/media")));
        XHTMLConverter.getInstance().convert(targetDocument, out, options);
    }
```

Comment: As stated by the error, the file you are trying to read is not in the correct `Office Open XML` format

Comment: @MarkiianBenovskyi I don't read from a file, i convert the string `str` to bytes then to XWPFDocument. the error display when i convert the byte to XWPFDocument.